# form.submit() not working normally

Tags: javascript, php, html

Having a bit of trouble here getting form.submit() to work normally. I'm looking into PHP for the first time and I'm sure how to locate my problem here. It looks like the Javascript is working normally. Whats strange is that if I create a normal  everything works normally. Unfortunately what I need to do is call form.submit() as an event handler on another input button located outside the form.

```
           <div id="top-header"></div>    
        <div id="form-container">
            <div id="location-section">
                <form id="customer-info" class="unselectable" unselectable='on' method="post" target="_blank">
                    Company name &nbsp
                    <input type="text" class="textInput" id="company-name" name="name">
                    <br>Street address
                    <input type="text" class="textInput" id="street-address" name="address">
                    <br>City
                    <input type="text" class="textInput"  id="city">
                    <br>State/Province
                    <input type="text" class="textInput"  id="state-province">
                    <br>Zip code
                    <input type="text" class="textInput"  id="zip-code">
                    <br>Country
                    <input type="text" class="textInput"  id="country">
                </form>
            </div>
```

I only put a name of two of the input elements for now, since I'm just trying to figure out what's wrong here.

Here's creating a variable for the form being submitted

```
var customerInfo = document.getElementById("customer-info");
```

I'm using some JQuery in this project so I have everything wrapped up in a $(document).ready();

Where Things get strange here is that my console.log() actually outputs "submit" normally, so this code is definitely being executed. This makes me thing my problem is something not so obvious (at least maybe not to me!)

```
    submit.addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log("Submit");
        customerInfo.submit();
});
```

Javascript

```
  <?php
 if(isset($_POST["name"]))
 {
   echo $_POST["name"];

}
else
{
    echo "no name provided";
}

if(isset($_POST["address"]))
{
     echo $_POST["address"];
}
else
{
     echo "no address provided";
}
?>
```

PHP

The more I look at this the more confounding I it is. It doesn't look like I made any obvious mistakes in creating my variables, so I'm curious what might be causing these problems.

Comment: Have you looked in your browser's Javascript console to see if there are any errors reported there? Also, what exactly _is_ happening currently? You just say that it's not working. But what does that mean?

Comment: Good questions- My console outputs "submit" normally as expected. I'm pretty familiar with javascript so I don't think its a syntax error that the browser would catch. in fact, the browser seems totally happy with this code- no scary  error messages of any sort. I should've mentioned this earlier but what happens Is is click on my submit button, and the browser opens a duplicate version of the page I'm already on.

Comment: Okay, so then is the PHP that you show above in the same file as your form code? As I mentioned in my comment to the answer below, leaving out the `action` attributed on the `form` element defaults to submitting the form to the same file that you have currently loaded. If the PHP code is in a different file, then you need to specify that (via the `action` attribute). If everything is in the same file, then please show all of the code together in the actual context instead of splitting it apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form does not have an `action` attribute. Therefore it will not do anything when you submit. You need to add an `action` attribute that hits that PHP endpoint.

Alternatively, add an `onclick` listener to the form, and do whatever work you want it to do on submit from this end instead.

Either way, your form does not currently have anything set up to "do" when you submit it, which is why it is not working!

Edit: as some people are pointing out in the comments, the `action` attribute [is not required](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp) in HTML 5. That being said, the fact that this code is not working still leads me to believe you should investigate this as a possible cause

Comment: The `action` defaults to the same/current file. So there's nothing inherently wrong with this, as long as the PHP code the OP shows in the question is actually in the same file as the form code.

Comment: Actually not having an action does do something. It will actually submit to the current url in most situations. Your answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: In any case, action attribute seems to have done it. My knowledge of PHP is very much still a work in progress so I expect my code to have a bit of wonkiness to it. Thank you for the assistance!